# How to fix "No such module 'FirebaseDatabaseUI'" in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4, firebaseui

I installed FirebaseDatabaseUI via Cocoapods, closed the .xcodeproj then opened the .xcodeworkspace, but whenever I try to import it within my code, it keeps saying `No such module 'FirebaseDatabaseUI'`

Supposing it might be a dependency issue, I decided to install the FirebaseUI full bundle by `pod 'FirebaseUI'`, but achieved no success at all. As can be seen in the screenshot I took of my code, FirebaseDatabaseUI is the only FirebaseUI library in which is occurring the issue.
[image: code]
Can someone tell me what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, all subspec like Database, Firestore, Auth... is implicitly belong to FirebaseUI. You saw only `FirebaseDatabaseUI` get error warning because you put it in the first place, if you put other FirebaseXYZUI to the first place, it will also display that error.

To fix the error, simply `import FirebaseUI` and remove all other FirebaseXYZUI.
Hope this helps.

Comment: It did not work at all. Now it keeps saying `No such module 'FirebaseUI'`. As specified [in the FirebaseUI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS#installing-firebaseui-for-ios), I should not even need to install all the specs, only the one I need, and that one is FirebaseDatabaseUI.

Comment: @WilerJr: Do you have "pod FirebaseUI" in your podfile? In Xcode10, I think you should restart Xcode project after doing pod install. And the documentation is right, if you need only FirebaseDatabaseUI, you only need "pod FirebaseUI/Database", but you still have to "import FirebaseUI" in your project.

Comment: I think something was really wrong within my project's settings. I had to start a new project and copy all my .swift files to it and do the pod install again. Then I followed your tips and it works like charm now. Thank you, @qtngo!